# As I am adding select statement in this query it returns nothing?

Tags: php, codeigniter

as i am running this query with select statement its returning nothing.

```
$this->db->select('emp_edu.qual_id','qual_title','pass_year','institute','percentage');
$this->db->from('emp_edu');
$this->db->join('qualification_mas', 'emp_edu.qual_id = qualification_mas.qual_id', 'INNER');
$this->db->where('emp_edu.emp_id', $empID);
$this->db->where('emp_edu.del_flag', 0);
$this->db->where('qualification_mas.del_flag', 0);
$query = $this->db->get();
return $query->result();
```

Comment: may be there are no results to display? or query properly not sent to sql server?

Comment: Have you tried outputting the query to a string and running it in a query tool like Toad or MySQL Workbench?

Comment: i used profiler. in that query is coming like  

    SELECT `emp_edu`.`qual_id`
    FROM (`emp_edu`)
    INNER JOIN `qualification_mas` ON `emp_edu`.`qual_id` =  `qualification_mas`.`qual_id`
    WHERE `emp_edu`.`emp_id` =  '6'
    AND `emp_edu`.`del_flag` =  0
    AND `qualification_mas`.`del_flag` =  0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
$this->db->select('emp_edu.qual_id','qual_title','pass_year','institute','percentage');
```

to

```
$this->db->select('emp_edu.qual_id,qual_title,pass_year,institute,percentage');
```

as you can see in system\database\active_rec.php
line 77

```
if (is_string($select))
            {
                $select = explode(',', $select);
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

`$this->db->select(
          array('emp_edu.qual_id','qual_title','pass_year','institute','percentage'));`

or you could enclose your parameter in `array`